# Use any object as mixin

Tags: ember.js

I want to share code between client and server side. I don't want a server roundtrip for data the client can calculate locally, but I also need to validate the data on the server side. As I don't have emberjs on the server, I use a normal JS object. Can I convert that to a mixin on the client side so I can mixin the functions to my model object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Ember mixin by wrapping the JS object literal in Ember.Mixin.create(). This is how many of the internal mixins are created, including Enumerable, etc.